# Best practice to convert webpart json xml to c# json string?

Tags: web-part, jsom

I did an export of the contentbysearchwebpart. I would like to create a new webpart with the same settings programmatically in c#. So I would like to set the property "DataProviderJSON". The json value in xml is:

```
{"QueryGroupName":"Default","QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl":"sitesearch://webroot","IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl":false,"SourceID":"8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89","SourceName":"Local SharePoint Results","SourceLevel":"Ssa","CollapseSpecification":"","QueryTemplate":"{searchboxquery} contentclass:\"STS_Site\" ","FallbackSort":[{"p":"ViewsRecent","d":1}],"FallbackSortJson":"[{\"p\":\"ViewsRecent\",\"d\":1}]","RankRules":null,"RankRulesJson":"null","AsynchronousResultRetrieval":false,"SendContentBeforeQuery":true,"BatchClientQuery":true,"FallbackLanguage":-1,"FallbackRankingModelID":"","EnableStemming":true,"EnablePhonetic":false,"EnableNicknames":false,"EnableInterleaving":false,"EnableQueryRules":true,"EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty":false,"HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit":-1,"IgnoreContextualScope":true,"ScopeResultsToCurrentSite":false,"TrimDuplicates":false,"Properties":{"TryCache":true,"Scope":"{Site.URL}","UpdateLinksForCatalogItems":true,"EnableStacking":true,"ListId":"ecf7cef6-a31e-451c-b97a-fc2201bba642","ListItemId":134},"PropertiesJson":"{\"TryCache\":true,\"Scope\":\"{Site.URL}\",\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true,\"ListId\":\"ecf7cef6-a31e-451c-b97a-fc2201bba642\",\"ListItemId\":134}","ClientType":"ContentSearchRegular","UpdateAjaxNavigate":true,"SummaryLength":180,"DesiredSnippetLength":90,"PersonalizedQuery":false,"FallbackRefinementFilters":null,"IgnoreStaleServerQuery":false,"RenderTemplateId":"DefaultDataProvider","AlternateErrorMessage":null,"Title":""}
```

This is my current code:

```
ContentBySearchWebPart cbswp = new ContentBySearchWebPart();
                cbswp.Title = "Overzichtspagina";
                cbswp.ItemTemplateId = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Item_Landingspagina.js";
                cbswp.RenderTemplateId = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Control_Landingspagina.js";
                cbswp.DataProviderJSON = ???
                cbswp.ResultsPerPage = 10;
                cbswp.ShowViewDuplicates = false;
                cbswp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
                webPartManager.AddWebPart(cbswp, "wpzSearchResult", 0);
                webPartManager.SaveChanges(cbswp);
```

What is the best practice to convert the json in xml format to a valid json string format?

Answer (score 0):

I entered the json value in notepad++. And I installed the json viewer plugin. I check if the value format is OK. After this I add a "\" character before each " character. Now it is like this:

```
searchWp.DataProviderJSON = "{  \"QueryGroupName\": \"Default\",    \"QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\": \"sitesearch://webroot\",   \"IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl\": false,    \"SourceID\": \"8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89\", \"SourceName\": \"Local SharePoint Results\",   \"SourceLevel\": \"Ssa\",   \"CollapseSpecification\": \"\",    \"QueryTemplate\": \"{searchboxquery} contentclass:STS_Site Path:http://myCompany.nl/* \", \"FallbackSort\": [{     \"p\": \"ViewsRecent\",     \"d\": 1    }], \"TrimDuplicates\": false, \"SummaryLength\": 180,\"DesiredSnippetLength\": 90 }";
```

Answer (score 0):

I also like using this format.

`string s = @"
{'QueryGroupName':'Default','QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl':'sitesearch://webroot','IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl':false,'SourceID':'8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89','SourceName':'Local SharePoint Results','SourceLevel':'Ssa','CollapseSpecification':'','QueryTemplate':'{searchboxquery} contentclass:'STS_Site' ','FallbackSort':[{'p':'ViewsRecent','d':1}],'FallbackSortJson':'[{'p':'ViewsRecent','d':1}]','RankRules':null,'RankRulesJson':'null','AsynchronousResultRetrieval':false,'SendContentBeforeQuery':true,'BatchClientQuery':true,'FallbackLanguage':-1,'FallbackRankingModelID':'','EnableStemming':true,'EnablePhonetic':false,'EnableNicknames':false,'EnableInterleaving':false,'EnableQueryRules':true,'EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty':false,'HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit':-1,'IgnoreContextualScope':true,'ScopeResultsToCurrentSite':false,'TrimDuplicates':false,'Properties':{'TryCache':true,'Scope':'{Site.URL}','UpdateLinksForCatalogItems':true,'EnableStacking':true,'ListId':'ecf7cef6-a31e-451c-b97a-fc2201bba642','ListItemId':134},'PropertiesJson':'{'TryCache':true,'Scope':'{Site.URL}','UpdateLinksForCatalogItems':true,'EnableStacking':true,'ListId':'ecf7cef6-a31e-451c-b97a-fc2201bba642','ListItemId':134}','ClientType':'ContentSearchRegular','UpdateAjaxNavigate':true,'SummaryLength':180,'DesiredSnippetLength':90,'PersonalizedQuery':false,'FallbackRefinementFilters':null,'IgnoreStaleServerQuery':false,'RenderTemplateId':'DefaultDataProvider','AlternateErrorMessage':null,'Title':'}
";`